# Steam game stuck after launching

Tags: games, steam

ALTITUDE launches perfectly, but gets stuck in login.

[image]

And it stays like that.

---

I am new to Ubuntu, I'll try to give further information if needed. In graphics it says Gallium 0.4 on AMD TURKS.

Comment: have you tried clicking, pressing Enter etc? And what version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: This smells like an awful way to try and sell a game.  Tricking troubleshooters in to buying a copy just to say "works for me"

Comment: also, what is your graphics, and the make/model/specs of you computer.

Comment: If it says "gallium" I don't think you graphics are properly installed try: http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux+x86

Comment: @hbdgaf - it's free, [available under Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/41300), and has [this](http://steamcommunity.com/app/41300/discussions/0/616189742993886456/) possibly relevant post that suggests installing Java, removing the Steam overlay, etc...

Comment: thanks  Mateo , that worked well for me , i installed ati package  from ubuntu softare centre